# Overiding placholders in django cms?

Tags: django, plugins, placeholder, django-cms

Hey im using the placeholder fields from django cms in some of my custom cms apps.  Basically what im trying to achieve is specific styles and filters for the same placeholder fields being used in different templates.

for example if i have a model for vacancies that looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField


# Create your models here.
class Vaccancy(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    ref_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    info = PlaceholderField('info')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="posistion active?")
```

and another model that also utilizes the placeholder field in a similar way.  What i hoped i could do is overide the tex.html template then have some conditional logic to detect the name of the placeholder  like so 
`{% ifequal placeholder "info" %}
    {{ body|truncatewords:200|safe }}
{% endifequal %}` the aim of this is so i can specify different filters like truncatewords etc as i dont want to apply this to every placeholder that uses a text plugin!

hope that was clear enough! cheers for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use placeholder fields, you have to check for `placeholder.slot`, also note that `{% if placeholder.slot == "info" %}` seems a bit nicer than `ifequal` :D